# pacman - list installed packages from given repo

Tags: arch-linux

How to list all installed packages coming from certain `repo` eg. `community`?

I want plain output (just a list of names) like this:

```
zynaddsubfx
xsel
...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try with `paclist`:

```
paclist - List all packages installed from a given repo
```

e.g. to list all packages installed from `community`:

```
paclist community
```

If you want only the names (w/o version number) you could use something like:

```
awk '{print $1}' <(paclist community)
```

or

```
cut -d' ' -f1 <(paclist community)
```

Comment: `paclist` does not seem to be a thing now; `pacman -S --search paclist` yields nothing; also, issuing `paclist` at the command line is not recognized.

Comment: @EricSmith - not sure what you mean... `paclist` is a very real thing on my up-to-date archlinux setup...

Comment: Found it; the key command; `pacman --files --search paclist`; apparently in the `pacman-contrib` package which I did not have installed.

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to install `pacman-contrib` package to achieve that goal:

```
pacman -Sl reponame | grep "\[installed\]"
```